# How to configure two ethernets eth0 and eth1 in debian 11?

Tags: linux, debian, networking, linux-kernel

I want to configure both eth0 and eth1 in debian 11.6

currently, I have configured it as follows

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static


address 192.168.1.125
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static


address 192.168.1.126
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.2
```

after configuring I'm able to ping only etho not eth1

any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: From where are you trying to ping the `eth1` address? This configuration looks a little odd because both interfaces are on the same network, and you've defined two default routes. Only one of those default routes is going to end up in your routing table (take a look at the output of `ip route`).

Comment: Why do you want to configure two interfaces to apparently the same network segment? Do you a) want more network bandwidth (use bonding/teaming), b) want two IP addresses in the same network segment (no second interface needed; just configure both IPs to the same interface), or c) the two interfaces are actually on separate network segments with conflicting IP address ranges (requires advanced routing configuration)? The answer to this question is important in figuring out the correct configuration.

Answer (score -2):

```
route add -net 192.168.1.126 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.1.2 dev eth1
```